# How to resolve main controller first then its child controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller as main controller and a its child controller. I want to execute first the main controller and then after its child controller.
I am collecting some userdata and want to keep it in $rootScope so that i could access it within the whole application.
How could i do this ?

```
<body ng-app="angularApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainAppController">
        <div ng-controller="childController">
            Here i want to access data from "MainAppController" stored in $rootScope
            But problem is "childController" runs before "MainAppController"
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the angular code

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('MainAppController', function($rootScope, service){
    $rootScope.userData = [];
    service.getUserData().success(function(userDetails){
        $rootScope.userData = userDetails;
    });
});

angular.module('MyApp').controller('childController', function($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.userInfo = $rootScope.userData;
    //Here $scope.userInfo is null because $rootScope.userData gets assigned to $scope.userInfo in this controller before userDetails gets assigned to $rootScope.userData in MainAppController controller.
    I want that untill "$rootScope.userData = userDetails;" is not finished , "$scope.userInfo = $rootScope.userData;" must not run.
    How can i do this ?
});
```

Comment: not clear what issue is . Child will inherit from parent http://plnkr.co/edit/V13KWwv76RiuG5CRdCa4?p=preview

Comment: Main controller is running some services from server, which is taking some time. I want that untill that services not resolved, child controller should not initialize

Comment: You clearly have not included enough code in your question. Show us exactly what's happening, not just the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways i know you can do this.

***1 way ::***
Use `$rootScope.userData`  directly in html and when your parent controller will run `$rootScope.userData` will get updated and by dual binding feature of angular, your view will get updated accordingly

Code::

```
//angularjs Code
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller('MainController', function($rootScope, $timeout) {
    $rootScope.userData = {};
    $timeout(function() {
        $rootScope.userData = {name:'myName'};
    }, 3000);
});

app.controller('childController', function() {

});
```

//html code

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div ng-controller="childController">
        {{userData.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

***2 way::***
You can attach $watch on `$rootScope.userData` in childController so when `$rootScope.userData` will get updated $watch will run and inside $watch you can update your $scope variable

```
Code::
//Angularjs Code
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
    app.controller('MainController', function($rootScope, $timeout) {
        $rootScope.userData = {};
        $timeout(function() {
            $rootScope.userData = {name:'myName'};
        }, 2000);
    });

    app.controller('childController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.$watch(function(){
            return $rootScope.userData;
        }, function(){
            $scope.userInfo = $rootScope.userData;
        });
    });
    //HTML Code
    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MainController">
        <div ng-controller="childController">
            {{userInfo.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
```